# emacs navigate through curly braces in if else blocks

Tags: emacs

GNU emacs 23.1.1

I am using emacs to debug some code. However, the if and else blocks are very big and I cannot display the whole code on my terminal as I have to scroll down many screens. And there are so many of them as most of them are nested, if hard to know which ones below to which if else block.

```
if(something)
{
 /* very big code block with nested if/elses */
}
else
{
/* very big code block with nested if/elses */
}
```

I would like to put the cursor on the first curly brace and somehow go to where this code block ends.

Hope you understand,

Many thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 21, accepted):

C-M-f - forward-sexp

This will take you to the } that matches the { point is ion.

Comment: ... and C-M-b will take you back. In this case cursor needs to be after the closing brace, whereas for C-M-f it needs to be "on" the opening brace. Also work for parenthesis and rectangle brackets "[]".

Comment: Funny, when I press the C-M it tabs a new space downwards.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I took the M as the 'm' key and not the 'Alt' key. Maybe need another ice coffee to keep me awake. Thanks.

Comment: Holding the Shift key while executing those commands selects the section of text inside the braces. (Or maybe "sets the mark at the previous position" is the correct Emacs lingo.) Very convenient.